# Twint Python library is causing exception for search query

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, twint

I have to collect some data from Twitter via Search. Unfortunately, its not possible to get Twitter API as they have rejected my request many times. I have decided to use [twint](https://github.com/twintproject/twint) python module for this purpose. I have installed latest version via git and then tried to search tweets for a string as follows:

```
twint -s pineapple
```

I get this exception

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/local/bin/twint", line 33, in 
> sys.exit(load_entry_point('twint==2.1.21', 'console_scripts', 'twint')())
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/twint/cli.py", line 339, in run_as_command
> main()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/twint/cli.py", line 330, in main
> run.Search(c)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/twint/run.py", line 410, in Search
> run(config, callback)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/twint/run.py", line 329, in run
> get_event_loop().run_until_complete(Twint(config).main(callback))
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 484, in run_until_complete
> return future.result()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/twint/run.py", line 235, in main
> await task
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/twint/run.py", line 286, in run
> await self.tweets()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/twint/run.py", line 217, in tweets
> await self.Feed()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/twint/run.py", line 62, in Feed
> response = await get.RequestUrl(self.config, self.init)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/twint/get.py", line 135, in RequestUrl
> response = await Request(_url, params=params, connector=_connector, headers=_headers)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/twint/get.py", line 161, in Request
> return await Response(session, _url, params)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/twint/get.py", line 167, in Response
> async with session.get(_url, ssl=True, params=params, proxy=httpproxy) as response:
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 855, in **aenter**
> self._resp = await self._coro
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 361, in _request
> ssl=ssl, proxy_headers=proxy_headers, traces=traces)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 207, in **init**
> url2 = url.with_query(params)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/yarl/**init**.py", line 857, in with_query
> new_query = self._get_str_query(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/yarl/**init**.py", line 837, in _get_str_query
> for k, v in query)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/yarl/**init**.py", line 837, in 
> for k, v in query)
>
> File "yarl/_quoting.pyx", line 226, in yarl._quoting._Quoter.**call**
>
> TypeError: Argument should be str

The installed version of python on my Ubuntu is 3.6. I have also imported `twint` in Python script but same exception appeared there also.

How to fix this issue ? Is there any best alternate for this task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall twint Using the  `pip uninstall twint`

and then reinstall it using

`pip install "git+https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git@origin/master#egg=twint"`

Hope this works

P.S. Incase you are using jupyter notebook try using the pip commands in the anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with python3.7 and resolve it by reinstalling yarl, like
this way:

```
pip3 install yarl --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir
```